# Fast bitwise operations on a long

Tags: java, performance, bit-shift

I know I can write the following method to calculate the set bit indexes of a long :

```
private static List<Integer> bitPositions(long number) {
    final List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
    int position = 1;
    while (number != 0) {
        if ((number & 1L) != 0) {
            positions.add(position);
        }
        position++;
        number = number >>> 1;
    }
    return positions;
}
```

My question is : **Is there a faster method to do this** ?

Comment: I hope number is not negative...

Comment: I'm actually not convinced that number being negative will cause problems.  Take for example: -8646761407372591104L.  This returns: [37, 39, 44, 48, 60, 64] which is correct.

Can you give a counter example?

Comment: The method should work fine regardless of the sign, since `>>>` is logical shift, which inserts zeroes at the other end and eventually fills every bit with zeroes, not arithmetic shift.

Comment: Depending on what is actually really required you could go faster if you remove building a list. The list is just a transformation of the information, so you *could* fuse testing logic and actual index processing, removing the need for boxing and the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Fastest method

[BitBank's answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41489337/7208029) is about twice as fast as this answer's two methods just below this one. This steals the idea in BitBank's answer and makes it about 73% faster than it on my machine (9 times faster than the question's method) by using bit twiddling to repeatedly turn off the least-significant one bit rather than right-shifting the one bit off the right end and keeping track of how much shifting has occurred.

```java
private static final byte[] bitPositions(long n) {
    final byte[] result = new byte[Long.bitCount(n)];

    for (int i = 0; n != 0L; i++) {
        result[i] = (byte) ((byte) Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(n) + 1);
        n &= n - 1L;  // Change least-significant one bit to a zero bit.
    }

    return result;
}
```

### Improvements on BitBank's answer

- No need to keep track of how many bits we've skipped past.
- Quickly turns the last one bit to a zero bit.
- The double cast to `byte` speeds things up slightly. I assume this is because it allows for `byte`-sized rather than `int`-sized arithmetic.

### Manual fusion

As Durandal pointed out in the question's comments, you can trade the following:

```java
for (int bitPosition : bitPositions(n)) {
    // Do something with `bitPosition`.
}
```

for a style that skips the method call and does this instead:

```java
long temp = n;
while (temp != 0L) {
    int bitPosition = Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(temp) + 1;
    temp &= temp - 1L;  // Change least-significant one bit to a zero bit.

    // Do something with `bitPosition`.
}
```

### Benefits of fusion

- No time wasted calling a method.
- No need to create or garbage collect an array, saving time and memory.
- The bit position can probably remain in a very fast CPU register the whole time you're using it rather than potentially needing to write it to an array in RAM (which is much slower) and then to read it back from RAM later on.

### Drawbacks of fusion

- It's a bit uglier than making a clearly-named method call and cleanly using an array of results.
- If you have multiple places in your code where you need to compute the bit positions of a number, you have to repeat code in each place (violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)).
- If you want to iterate multiple separate times through the bit positions of the same number, you have to compute the bit positions over again rather than reusing a previously generated array.

  This might not be an actual drawback, though, if computing a bit position anew is quicker than loading a precomputed one from an array in RAM.

---

## Slowest method

Here's a method that produces the same results (just in a `byte[]` instead of a `List<Integer>`) about twice as fast:

```java
private static final byte[] bitPositions(long n) {
    final byte[] result = new byte[Long.bitCount(n)];

    int i = 0;
    for (byte bit = 1; n != 0L; bit++) {
        if ((n & 1L) != 0) result[i++] = bit;
        n >>>= 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'd recommend changing `byte bit = 1` in the `for` loop to `byte bit = 0` to switch to the traditional method of numbering bit positions starting with zero instead of one.

### Improvements

- Precomputing the needed capacity with `Long.bitCount(n)` (uses the very speedy "popcount" instruction of your processor) speeds up your method quite a bit. You can change this by making the `ArrayList` using `new ArrayList<>(Long.bitCount(n))`.
- Using an `ArrayList<Integer>` is slower than a `byte[]`, because:

  - Time must be wasted looking up low-valued (`-127` to `128`) `Integer` values from [the `Integer` cache](http://javapapers.com/java/java-integer-cache/) to put them into the `ArrayList`.
  - Time must be wasted when using the `int`s stored in the resulting `List<Integer>` later on because you have to both retrieve the `Integer` from the `List<Integer>` and then retrieve the `int` from the `Integer`.
- A `byte[]` uses about 1/4th (32-bit system) or 1/8th (64-bit system) the memory of an `ArrayList<Integer>`, since `byte`s are that much smaller than pointers to `Integer`s.

---

## Slightly faster than slowest method, but uglier

As suggested by another person's deleted answer, loop unrolling speeds things up a little bit further on my machine (check whether that's true on your machine as well):

```java
private static final byte[] bitPositions(final long n) {
    final byte[] result = new byte[Long.bitCount(n)];

    int i = 0;
    if ((n &                    1L) != 0L) result[i++] = 1;
    if ((n &                    2L) != 0L) result[i++] = 2;
    if ((n &                    4L) != 0L) result[i++] = 3;
    if ((n &                    8L) != 0L) result[i++] = 4;
    if ((n &                   16L) != 0L) result[i++] = 5;
    if ((n &                   32L) != 0L) result[i++] = 6;
    if ((n &                   64L) != 0L) result[i++] = 7;
    if ((n &                  128L) != 0L) result[i++] = 8;
    if ((n &                  256L) != 0L) result[i++] = 9;
    if ((n &                  512L) != 0L) result[i++] = 10;
    if ((n &                 1024L) != 0L) result[i++] = 11;
    if ((n &                 2048L) != 0L) result[i++] = 12;
    if ((n &                 4096L) != 0L) result[i++] = 13;
    if ((n &                 8192L) != 0L) result[i++] = 14;
    if ((n &                16384L) != 0L) result[i++] = 15;
    if ((n &                32768L) != 0L) result[i++] = 16;
    if ((n &                65536L) != 0L) result[i++] = 17;
    if ((n &               131072L) != 0L) result[i++] = 18;
    if ((n &               262144L) != 0L) result[i++] = 19;
    if ((n &               524288L) != 0L) result[i++] = 20;
    if ((n &              1048576L) != 0L) result[i++] = 21;
    if ((n &              2097152L) != 0L) result[i++] = 22;
    if ((n &              4194304L) != 0L) result[i++] = 23;
    if ((n &              8388608L) != 0L) result[i++] = 24;
    if ((n &             16777216L) != 0L) result[i++] = 25;
    if ((n &             33554432L) != 0L) result[i++] = 26;
    if ((n &             67108864L) != 0L) result[i++] = 27;
    if ((n &            134217728L) != 0L) result[i++] = 28;
    if ((n &            268435456L) != 0L) result[i++] = 29;
    if ((n &            536870912L) != 0L) result[i++] = 30;
    if ((n &           1073741824L) != 0L) result[i++] = 31;
    if ((n &           2147483648L) != 0L) result[i++] = 32;
    if ((n &           4294967296L) != 0L) result[i++] = 33;
    if ((n &           8589934592L) != 0L) result[i++] = 34;
    if ((n &          17179869184L) != 0L) result[i++] = 35;
    if ((n &          34359738368L) != 0L) result[i++] = 36;
    if ((n &          68719476736L) != 0L) result[i++] = 37;
    if ((n &         137438953472L) != 0L) result[i++] = 38;
    if ((n &         274877906944L) != 0L) result[i++] = 39;
    if ((n &         549755813888L) != 0L) result[i++] = 40;
    if ((n &        1099511627776L) != 0L) result[i++] = 41;
    if ((n &        2199023255552L) != 0L) result[i++] = 42;
    if ((n &        4398046511104L) != 0L) result[i++] = 43;
    if ((n &        8796093022208L) != 0L) result[i++] = 44;
    if ((n &       17592186044416L) != 0L) result[i++] = 45;
    if ((n &       35184372088832L) != 0L) result[i++] = 46;
    if ((n &       70368744177664L) != 0L) result[i++] = 47;
    if ((n &      140737488355328L) != 0L) result[i++] = 48;
    if ((n &      281474976710656L) != 0L) result[i++] = 49;
    if ((n &      562949953421312L) != 0L) result[i++] = 50;
    if ((n &     1125899906842624L) != 0L) result[i++] = 51;
    if ((n &     2251799813685248L) != 0L) result[i++] = 52;
    if ((n &     4503599627370496L) != 0L) result[i++] = 53;
    if ((n &     9007199254740992L) != 0L) result[i++] = 54;
    if ((n &    18014398509481984L) != 0L) result[i++] = 55;
    if ((n &    36028797018963968L) != 0L) result[i++] = 56;
    if ((n &    72057594037927936L) != 0L) result[i++] = 57;
    if ((n &   144115188075855872L) != 0L) result[i++] = 58;
    if ((n &   288230376151711744L) != 0L) result[i++] = 59;
    if ((n &   576460752303423488L) != 0L) result[i++] = 60;
    if ((n &  1152921504606846976L) != 0L) result[i++] = 61;
    if ((n &  2305843009213693952L) != 0L) result[i++] = 62;
    if ((n &  4611686018427387904L) != 0L) result[i++] = 63;
    if ((n & -9223372036854775808L) != 0L) result[i++] = 64;

    return result;
}
```

You can also change this to start counting the bit positions at zero instead of one.

### Improvements

- Avoids the need to repeatedly perform `>>>` on the number.
- Avoids the need to repeatedly perform `++` on the bit positon.
- Avoids needing to check whether the number has reached zero.
- Avoids some branch mispredictions.

Comment: Thank you !  Great explanation.

Comment: `byte[]` is preferable because it packs the memory into about 1/4 the space of a `int[]`. Also, Java will autoconvert `byte`s to `int`s, so you can do things like `int a = result[5];` or `result[5] * 500` and get a result as if `result[5]` had been an `int` all along (the multiplication by `500` won't overflow because everything is treated as an `int`), and things will work as if the array was of `int`s. Basically, you're getting less memory usage for free.

Comment: How do you know it's quicker? Have you measured it or is it a logical conclusion? Avoiding branches would be nice but I'm not sure how it could be done...

Comment: @assylias By branches missing, I mean the `for` loop's condition (`n != 0L`) doesn't need to be checked anymore since that `for` loop is gone in the uglier version. As for measurements, I did an unrigorous measurement with a million iterations of each (with `java.util.Random` providing the inputs) and used `time java ClassName`. The uglier one came in several times at around 0.35s, the not-so-ugly one came in several times at about 0.38s, and the code in the question came in several times at about 0.60s.

Comment: I had initially suggested using the unrolling loop approach, I deleted it because it required a full 64 comparisons, whereas the original loop stopped as soon as the most significant bit was identified, which probably will happen after far less than 64 bits. A better approach would be to reverse the order of the comparisons, starting at bit 64, and then put the first 32 bits inside an if block that checked if the number was larger than 2^32. At the end of that if block, remove the top 32 bits from the source number. Then repeat for the next 16 bits, and then the next 8 and then the final 8.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using intrinsics, you can have an even faster version. [`Long.numberOfTrailingZeros()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#numberOfTrailingZeros-long-) will use the CPU intrinsic that [counts the number of consecutive zero bits starting from the least-significant bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#Hardware_support) (the [`BSF` instruction](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/spr2002/books/labmanual/inst-ref-bsf.html) on x86 processors).

For a sparse value, this will be faster than all other looping methods because it doesn't have any conditionals or branches within the main loop, it skips runs of any number of 0's with a single iteration, and, for a 64-bit `long`, the `BSF` intrinsic has [a latency of only 3 clock cycles](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) on Intel Haswell CPUs.

```java
private static final byte[] bitPositions(long n) {
    final byte[] result = new byte[Long.bitCount(n)];

    byte bitPosition = 0;
    for (int i = 0; n != 0L; i++) {
        final byte bitsToSkip = (byte) (Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(n) + 1);
        n >>>= bitsToSkip;
        bitPosition += bitsToSkip;
        result[i] = bitPosition;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Can you explain why this method is faster than the other solutions presented for 'sparse' values?  Again thanks, I find this to be a readable approach, and I don't mind using the JDK API's

Comment: @AmirAfghani It's also twice as fast on average for `long`s in general than my two methods (or about four times as fast as the method in the question). I recommend this method instead of mine.

Comment: Thanks @ChaiT.Rex - this approach still needs to be cleaned up a bit.  It currently doesn't compile as Java, and the signature doesn't conform to the API the same way your approach does.  Did you test this method by having it return a byte[] ?  Would be curious to see you include the results in your answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Chai. I tested it in C and no longer have a working Java environment, so I'm trusting that your new version will do as the OP intended. The main point was to make use of intrinsics/SIMD when possible.

Comment: @BitBank I tested that the results of the question's method matches the results of this version for a million random `long`s. Your idea of using intrinsics is very nice, as it consistently gives the following results for a million iterations on my machine in the past few minutes: intrinsics-all-the-way: 0.18s, my-loop-unrolling: 0.35s, method-in-the-question: 0.69s.

Answer (score 1):

Here I used a simple approach, sublinear time.  You decide if you count from left or from right, in `printf("%ld\n", 32-pos)` you can consider `32-pos` or `pos`.

```
bit_pos(unsigned long x)
{
    unsigned long pos;
    unsigned long w;
    while(x) {
        /* extract the rightmost `1` in `w` then remove it */
        w = x&-x;
        x-=w;

        if (w) {
            /* compute number of trailing zeros (location of 1) for w */
            pos = 1;
            if (!(w >> 16)) {pos+=16;w<<=16;}
            if (!(w >> 24)) {pos+= 8;w<<= 8;}
            if (!(w >> 28)) {pos+= 4;w<<= 4;}
            if (!(w >> 30)) {pos+= 2;w<<= 2;}
            pos = pos - (w >> 31);
            printf("%ld\n", 32-pos);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

main()
{
    bit_pos(2UL+4+32+1024);
    bit_pos(3456789UL);
}
```